# pushViewcontroller confused me

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

when I use this code

```
CommentController *commentCont  = [[CommentController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController: commentCont animated:YES];
```

the error "Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported" occurs .

But when I stop at the line2 and the following debug information shows that commentCont isn't in the navigation stack. so why this error happen?

```
po [self.navigationController viewControllers]
$0 = 0x0764a7e0 <__NSArrayI 0x764a7e0>(
<SideBarViewController: 0x91195a0>,
<DetailShowController: 0x72638a0>
```

Comment: Is the pushViewController being called multiple times?

Comment: @verbumdei,no, just once, i can make sure